# how do I group all the distinct number using ramdajs

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Suppose, I have an array which contains value [1,1,2,2,3,3]. I want to group all the distinct number in this array so I should have the result like this `{ "0": [1,2,3], "1": [1,2,3] }`
So here what I have tried. The inital value actually start at 1-99 so if I % by 10 all will have something like [0,..,9,0,...,9] and after that I don't know what to do next.

```
const test = compose(
    groupBy(i => ...),
    map(i => i % 10),
    range
  )(1, 10*10);
```

this worked for me

```
const test = compose(
    mapObjIndexed((value,key,obj) => value.map((numb,index) => obj[index][key])),
    groupBy(i => i),
    map(i => i % 10),
    range
  )(1, 10*10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list is sorted, it *could* be as simple as:

*This may be an oversimplification of your problem at hand but this solution may be enough to get you started*

```js
const group = compose(transpose, groupWith(equals));

console.log(group([1,1,2,2,3,3]));
//=> [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {compose, equals, groupWith, transpose} = R;</script>
```

**What's happening here?**

First `groupWith(equals)` creates sequences of similar *adjacent* numbers (which is why the list *must* be sorted)

```js
groupWith(equals, [1,1,2,2,3,3]);
//=> [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])
```

Then `transpose` will create from *x* lists of *n* length, *n* lists of *x* length:

```js
transpose([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])
//=> [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

We had 3 lists of 2 items, we now have 2 lists of 3 items.

It should now be easy to produce a map from it if necessary.

Comment: Nice use of transpose.

Comment: Agreed on the `transpose`.  My answer simply extends this to allow unsorted input and return the results in the strange requested format.

Answer (score 2):

The idea [customcommander presents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62192232) of using `transpose` makes this pretty easy.  Two further steps seem to get you fully to your goal... if I understand that goal correctly.  First, we can replace `groupWith(equals)` with `groupBy(identity)` followed by `values`; this means it no longer matters whether the input is sorted.  Second, if you really want the `{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [1, 2, 3]}` output rather than the more common `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`, we can end with a `toPairs`/`fromPairs` shuffle (equivalently, `Object.entries`/`Object.fromEntries`.)  On a plain object, that would be a no-op.  But on an array, it converts it to an object with such integer keys.

```js
const group = pipe (
  groupBy (identity),
  values,
  transpose,
  toPairs,
  fromPairs
) 

console .log (group ([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]))

console .log (group ([1, 5, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, groupBy, identity, values, transpose, toPairs, fromPairs} = R </script>
```

So this is my understanding of what you're trying to achieve.  Please let me know if this is wrong:

The output is an object with keys being the small non-negative integers (`0`, `1`, `2`, ...).  Key `0` has the unique values from the original input.  Key `1` has the unique values remaining after you remove one of each element of key `0` from the input.  Key `2` has the unique values remaining after you remove one of each element of key `0` from the input and then one of each element of key `1` from the remainder, and so forth.

Note that although the results have the elements sorted, that's a happy accident, based on the strange key-sorting algorithm for small integers in JS.  If you were to replace the `1`'s by `a`'s, the `2`'s by `b`'s and so forth in the second example, the results would be sorted differently:

```js
console .log (group (['a', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']))
//=> {"0":["a","e","b","d","c"],"1":["a","b","d","c"],"2":["a","b","c"],"3":["a","b","c"],"4":["a"],"5":["a"],"6":["a"]}
```

If this is an issue, you could end the pipeline with `map (sortBy (identity))`.

Comment: `groupBy(identity)` to get rid of the sorted list requirement was a good call. Nice.

Comment: Ramda really needs a function that performs `groupBy(foo)` followed by `values`.  I keep meaning to do that, but never seem to get around to it.

Comment: Don't blame yourself... ;) I never finished this PR https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/2715 - I really should finish it! Challenge considered.

Comment: Ahh, *that's* why I never dropped it.  Not because I'm slow and lazy.  Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object which keeps the index for the target of the same value.

This approach fills the first arrays first.

```js
var data = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    indices = {},
    result = {};

for (let value of data) {
    if (!indices[value]) indices[value] = 0;
    const index = indices[value]++;
    if (!result[index]) result[index] = [];
    result[index].push(value);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks I applied your idea in ramdajs and now it works

Comment: @Patrick: I'm curious how you converted these ideas to Ramda.  This answer is based around side effect and mutation, neither of which works well with Ramda.  Could you share your code?

Comment: Thank you @Patrick.  I'm afraid I still don't really understand your requirements, nor how that code maps to this one, but I'm glad you found an answer you like.